# Is it possible to put the button on the right center in a ´position: sticky´ and that in the mobile version it would disappear?

Tags: html, css, button, html-helper, sticky

Is it possible to put the button on the right center in a ´position: sticky´ and that in the mobile version it would disappear?
Right now its appear on all versions , I need only on Web and tablet

```
<div style="top: 75%; position: sticky; z-index: 1;">
<div style="position: absolute; right: -1.5%;">
<a href="..." class="btn-secondary h-red"
style="padding: 10px 34px 10px 20px;
font-size: 13px; font-weight:
700; border-radius: 20px;">Support</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First add an `id` or `class` or any other identifier to your element of choice in HTML:

```
<div style="top: 75%; position: sticky; z-index: 1;" id="yourStickyButton">
```

In CSS:
If the browser window is 480px or smaller, the button will disappear:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #yourStickyButton{
    display:none;
  }
}
```